# Convert complicated postgresql query into trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql query that takes data that is in an indexed format and converts it to regular text. For example:

But this is not working properly due to syntax errors. Any advice on how to format this properly?

Comment: remove the `:` after `IS NOT NULL` and add a `then` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Comment: Read this [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) and [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) . In meantime  lose the `SET` and you need to qualify the values e.g. NEW.key, NEW.abstract_inverted_index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

simplified query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ((js::jsonb) -> 'InvertedIndex') AS unnested_js
    FROM (
        VALUES ('{"IndexLength":97,"InvertedIndex":{"Environmental":[0],"exposure":[1],"is":[2]}}')) ss (js)
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        (jsonb_each(unnested_js)).*
    FROM
        cte
    ORDER BY
        2
)
SELECT
    string_agg(key, ' ' ORDER BY value)
FROM
    cte1;
```

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=774ce44a756e6029ce8979bdea10ff96)

- You need **before** insert/update trigger, so that you can modified the new record and return new record.
- If key 'InvertedIndex' not exists then make code run to another case condition branch immediately.
- raise notice is for debug purpose.
- I did not consider the case that new.abstract_inverted_index cannot cast to jsonb.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_convert_abstract_index ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'new abstract_inverted_index is %', NEW.abstract_inverted_index;
    RAISE NOTICE 'key exists: %', ((NEW.abstract_inverted_index)::jsonb)['InvertedIndex'] IS NOT NULL;
    IF NEW.abstract_inverted_index IS NOT NULL AND ((NEW.abstract_inverted_index)::jsonb)['InvertedIndex'] IS NOT NULL THEN
        _sql := ( WITH cte AS (
                SELECT
                    ((js::jsonb) -> 'InvertedIndex') AS unnested_js
                FROM (
                    VALUES (NEW.abstract_inverted_index)) ss (js)),
                cte1 AS (
                    SELECT
                        (jsonb_each(unnested_js)).*
                    FROM
                        cte
                    ORDER BY
                        2
)
                    SELECT
                        string_agg(key, ' ' ORDER BY value)
                    FROM
                        cte1);
        NEW.abstract := _sql;
        RAISE NOTICE 'new.abstract: %', NEW.abstract;
        RAISE NOTICE 'new: %', ROW (NEW.*);
        RETURN new;
    ELSE
        NEW.abstract := 'test';
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger to be able to modify the new record. Also use a much simpler subquery for creating the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_convert_abstract_index()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.abstract_inverted_index IS NOT NULL:
         NEW.abstract = (
             SELECT string_agg(key, ' ' ORDER BY (value->>0)::int)
             FROM jsonb_each(abstract_inverted_index::jsonb -> 'InvertedIndex')
         );
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```